# Unexpected corner coordinates after change in reference system using GDAL

Tags: python, raster, coordinate-system, gdal

I'm working with the [ESA CCI land cover rasters](https://www.esa-landcover-cci.org/). I'm trying to window and project them, but the results aren't what I expect.

If I run `ncdump -h -s` on one of the ESA CCI raster NetCDFs I get:

```
crs:wkt = "GEOGCS[\"WGS 84\", \n",
        "  DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\", \n",
        "    SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, \
             AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7030\"]], \n",
        "    AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6326\"]], \n",
        "  PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\", 0.0, AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]], \n",
        "  UNIT[\"degree\", 0.017453292519943295], \n",
        "  AXIS[\"Geodetic longitude\", EAST], \n",
        "  AXIS[\"Geodetic latitude\", NORTH], \n",
        "  AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]]" ;
```

I know also that the raster is 'north-up'...in the metadata from that same `ncdump` it is written: `geospatial_lat_units = "degrees_north"`.

Now that I know the raster bounds, orientation and coordinate reference system (WGS84 = EPSG:4326), I attempt to window and project the raster using GDAL. I wish to project the data into EPSG:3035 (= ETRS89 = Europe), so I look up the bbox extent on [epsg.io/3035](http://epsg.io/3035) and read the following:

```
Projected bounds:
1896628.62 1507846.05
4656644.57 6827128.02

WGS84 bounds:
-16.1 32.88
39.65 84.17
```

With this in mind, I go ahead and make an attempt with the following (Python) script:

```
import os

os.system('gdal_translate -of vrt -a_ullr -180 90 180 -90 -a_srs "EPSG:4326" HDF5:"ESACCI-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-2015-v2.0.7.nc"://lccs_class esacci.vrt')
os.system('gdalwarp -overwrite -of vrt -te_srs "EPSG:4326" -te -16.1 32.8 39.65 84.17 esacci.vrt esacci2.vrt')
os.system('gdalwarp -overwrite -s_srs "EPSG:4326" -t_srs "EPSG:3035" esacci2.vrt esacci.tif')
```

A glance at the resulting TIFF makes it seem like everything is in order. Furthermore, when I run `gdalinfo` on esacci2.vrt the corner coordinates are as expected (by epsg.io/3035):

```
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84" ….]

Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -16.1000000,  84.1700000) ( 16d 6' 0.00"W, 84d10'12.00"N)
Lower Left  ( -16.1000000,  32.8000000) ( 16d 6' 0.00"W, 32d48' 0.00"N)
Upper Right (  39.6500000,  84.1700000) ( 39d39' 0.00"E, 84d10'12.00"N)
Lower Right (  39.6500000,  32.8000000) ( 39d39' 0.00"E, 32d48' 0.00"N)
Center      (  11.7750000,  58.4850000) ( 11d46'30.00"E, 58d29' 6.00"N)
```

HOWEVER, when I run `gdalinfo` on esacci.tif...the corner coordinates do not match what is predicted by epsg.io/3035:

```
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["ETRS89 / LAEA Europe" ….]

Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 1894132.863, 6827128.020) ( 71d33' 9.14"W, 68d52'45.48"N)
Lower Left  ( 1894132.863, 1086761.052) ( 14d56'32.27"W, 29d14'19.31"N)
Upper Right ( 7060793.737, 6827128.020) ( 93d51'27.16"E, 66d16' 0.52"N)
Lower Right ( 7060793.737, 1086761.052) ( 37d59'10.65"E, 28d17' 0.95"N)
Center      ( 4477463.300, 3956944.536) ( 12d41'37.11"E, 58d41'13.10"N)
```

I can further replicate the EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3035 transform described on epsg.io/3035 with OSR, where the following results in the correct/predicted coordinates...which again are not what esacci.tif lists:

```
from osgeo import osr

s_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
s_srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
t_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
t_srs.ImportFromEPSG(3035)

transform = osr.CreateCoordinateTransformation(s_srs, t_srs)

print(transform.TransformPoint(-16.1, 32.88))
print(transform.TransformPoint(39.65, 84.17))
```

What am I missing and/or doing wrong here?

Comment: Why VRT format? What happens if you use -of GTIFF? Why are you warping twice? you can get a box from the original with -projwin ULX ULY LRX LRY or with your -te, like on the 2nd warp, but supply the -t_srs as one operation.

Comment: Putting the `gdalwarp` statement all on one line results in correct projected corner coords (from `gdalinfo`)! But the resulting TIFF does not seem correct (half of EU is clipped, part of NA shows). Alternatively, using a `gdal_translate -projwin` instead of the first `gdalwarp` yields similar results (correct corner coords, incorrect extent after visual check)...very confused..it seems a tradeoff: correct physical extent or correct corner coords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is conceptual and contradictory to the question the results were more or less as expected (minor discrepancy noted by Antonio Falciano's answer due to a missing hundred's place '8' in the bounds):

Projected bounds are not the same thing as the corner coordinates of a rectangular raster (after projection, if the result is not rectangular, missing value padding is added in order to create a rectangle..).

Answer (score 3):

You simply miss an `8` in `-te -16.1 32.8 39.65 84.17`: according to the bounds you have reported, it should be 32.88, not 32.8 in the first `gdalwarp` command.

Although, there's a more elegant way to convert & transform your data using `gdalwarp` as library function:

```
from osgeo import gdal

ds_in = gdal.Open('HDF5:"ESACCI-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-2015-v2.0.7.nc"://lccs_class')
ds_out = gdal.Warp('esacci.tif', ds_in, 
                   format = 'GTiff',
                   dstSRS = 'EPSG:3035',
                   outputBounds = [-16.1, 32.88, 39.65, 84.17],
                   outputBoundsSRS = 'EPSG:4326')

# if you want to check the result
print gdal.Info(ds_out)

ds_out = None
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it is true I forgot an 8! But that doesn't explain the magnitude of discrepancy I reported. In the end the issue was conceptual/trivial/basic: projected bounds are not the same thing as the corner coordinates of a rectangular raster..